# Is $y'=1+y^n$ periodic function for $n>2$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Is $y'=1+y^n$ periodic function for  $n>2$ ?
Under the condition: $y(0)=0$

If  $n=2$  then $y(x)=\tan(x)$
and we know that the period of $\tan(x)$ function is $\pi$.

If $y_n(x)$ are periodic for $n>2$,How can the period of $y_n(x)$  be found as the function of $n$  $(T(n))$?

If they are not periodic for $n>2$, please help me prove it.

Thanks for answers and advice

Comment: The solution is not periodic for $n=3$. See [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D1%2By%5E3).

Comment: @lhf  Please check for $n=2$ , same kind of graph it draws.http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%3D1%2By%5E2

Comment: Do you have evidence that it may be periodic apart from the $n=2$ case?  This is an enormous generalization otherwise.

Comment: @vadim123 The inverse function can be expressed as $a_1\ln(y-y_1)+a_2\ln(y-y_2)+...+a_n\ln(y-y_n)=x+c$ and then $(y-y_1)^{a_{1}}(y-y_2)^{a_{2}}...(y-y_n)^{a_{n}}=Ke^{x}$ . I think that way but I do not know how to go forward to prove they are periodic  like $tan(x)$.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When $n=2$, it is odd to state that $y'=1+y^2$ has a periodic solution of period $\pi$ since no solution of this equation is defined on an interval of length greater than $\pi$.